# Python Admin Site with Through Parameter

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I had the following Model

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

With my Admin.py below, The query set worked 100% (basically only showing users in the current group and users not in a group at all )

```
class UserGroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('users',)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'users':
            object_id = request.resolver_match.kwargs.get('object_id')
            kwargs['queryset'] = User.objects.filter(
                Q(usergroup=None) | Q(usergroup=object_id)
            )
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(UserGroup, UserGroupAdmin)
```

The output looked like the below

[image]

Which was great but I changed my Model to use the Through parameter below.

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, through='UserToUserGroup')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class UserToUserGroup(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    user_group = models.ForeignKey(UserGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now My admin site looks like the below.

[image]

I am having a hard time getting the admin site to look same after my changes to the model. I am still getting use to working with the admin site. I tried some inlines but had no success. I do need to use the filter horizontal and have it look the same.

Comment: Yoursecond implementation would allow a user to only be part of *one* `UserGroup`?

Comment: Yes that is one of the 'Rules'. A user should only be allowed to be in one group or none at all